# Binary data in TeX \special

Tags: output, specials

I want to ask if I can output binary information in `\special`? If it is possible, how do I put the binary in TeX source? In C/C++, for instance `\0` can be used to get the byte `00000000` so what could be the equivalent for TeX?

Comment: Can you please tell what such a `\special` would be useful for?

Comment: To assist DVI rendering (for e.g. outputing point coordinates in binary instead of strings would be much faster to parse and process in application such as extending SyncTeX to DVI) and enhance DVI graphic capability (for e.g. including PNG in DVI file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean, can I type `\special` followed by something, into the `.tex` source, file to get binary data into the DVI file, then the answer is no (but see below). This is because in TeX `\special` is not really special: it's just a primitive command (like `\def` or `\write`), and it simply writes out the tokens that are given inside `\special{...}`, while expanding them and so on (like `\edef` or `\xdef`). As it's hard to get arbitrary binary data into a TeX token list, you cannot get that written out to a DVI file. (However, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399260/input-tokens-through-the-unicode-position/399287#399287) which points out a way it may be possible (just possible, not easy!) using `pdflatex -8bit`.)

The relevant sections from the TeX program (see it with [`texdoc tex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf)), showing that `\special` uses `show_token_list` etc.:

[image: <code>\special</code>]
[image: <code>\special</code>]

Even if you could get binary data written out from the TeX source, would it work? The DVI format itself supports arbitrary binary data inside specials (aka the `xxx1` to `xxx4` commands). However, there is a convention that the data is text; in fact `dvitype` gives an error or warning when an `xxx` command contains non-ASCII data.

[image: <code>dvitype</code>]

Of course this may just be a convention from the time of when DVItype was written (last updated 1995), and I haven't examined the DVI specials produced by various packages (or what XeTeX does in its `.xdv` format). So it is possible that you can have binary data there and get away with it — at least in some DVI drivers, as interpreting the special is entirely up to the DVI driver. But if you are writing your own DVI driver (which is assumed if you're putting unusual specials there), then you might as well instead write the binary data in base64 or some such ASCII-only encoding, and then have the driver decode it into arbitrary data.