# input tokens through the unicode position

Tags: tex-core, unicode, input-encodings

With luatex I can inject tokens with a command through their unicode positions (see the following example). I'm wondering if this could be done with pdflatex too.

It doesn't need to have all the features of the luatex example.

It is ok

- if utf8 encoding of the file is assumed
- if it doesn't work directly for all unicode blocks and some preprocessing for a block is needed
- if this preprocessing must be done after some `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or similar definitions.
- if the input must be in lowercase (20ac) instead of (20AC)
- if the command is not expandable and so doesn't work in an \edef (the luatex version works there if the current meaning of € is expandable).

### luatex example

```
%run with lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function inserttokenbyunicodeposition (unicodeposition)
 tex.sprint("^^^^"..string.lower(unicodeposition))
end
\end{luacode} 

\newcommand\unicodetoutf[1]{\directlua{inserttokenbyunicodeposition("#1")}}

\newcommand\unicodetoutfchar[1]{\char"#1} 

\begin{document}
\catcode`\€=\active \def€{Hallo}

€ ^^^^20ac \unicodetoutf{20AC} %<-- should output Hallo

\unicodetoutfchar{20AC} %<-- unwanted output   

\end{document}
```

### pdflatex MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{Hallo}

\newcommand\unicodetoutf[1]{??}

\begin{document}

€ ^^e2^^82^^ac \unicodetoutf{20AC} %<-- should output Hallo

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems you want to exploit the conversion from Unicode to UTF-8 used by `inputenc`.

Comment: Do you know how to input a character given its hex code, i.e. how to define `\puthex` such that `\puthex{e2}` is equivalent to typing `^^e2`? (Or input could be in decimal like `\puthex{226}` if that's easier.) I have everything else except this… maybe I should ask a separate question. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I thought about this too but imho the processing of the ^^-notation is earlier than the macro processing.

Comment: You are right, I deleted my comment mentioning the trick that doesn't work (`\uccode` and `\uppercase`). So still not sure how to do it, or even whether it's possible. Now I think converting 20AC to the list [e2, 82, ac] is the easy part, how to input those tokens? (I don't understand how the current answer works either…)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR the current answer cheats a bit: It doesn't input the equivalent to `^^e2^^82^^ac` in the input stream but directly calls the inputenc/utf8 definition. So it is not like the lualatex version but unless there is some magic tric e.g. with \scantokens I have some doubts that one can get more in pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed the cheating, figured out some magic with `\scantokens` indeed :-)

Comment: Related question from 2013 (with top voted answer by @UlrikeFischer): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89796/unicode-characters-in-pdflatex-output-using-hexcode-without-utf-8-input/89855#89855

Comment: @UlrikeFischer my upd. ans. inserts into token stream equivalent of ``^^e2^^82^^ac`` UTF-8 bytes (after expansion but without `\scantokens`). As it is expandable it can be used to create out of the blue UTF-8 encoded files from pdflatex. Paradoxically, the most complicated is the ascii-range. As far as I know one can not get pdftex to output for example a NUL byte, it will always put ``^^@`` in the file, despite the token being really an ascii code zero internally. But `\UniToUTF{0}` does produce via expansion a catcode 12 ascii code zero token and will use slot 0 of current (tex) font, etc...

Comment: @jfbu I saw your edits but can't check now, fighting with a csv-table that doesn't like to be input ...

Comment: (my comment above is solved by TCX files or by the ``-8bit`` option of pdflatex)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### udpated:

Since 2018/04/01 LaTeX release, inputenc+utf8 is active (sic) by default, and this broke the v3 approach below, because the ascii bytes in range 128-255 are now active and they were assumed here of catcode 12.

I have made a small edit to my v3 code to let it be usable both with  or without inputenc loaded for old LaTeX or with new LaTeX.

**(pdflatex only answer)**

### Table of contents

- **v1** and **v2** exploit already existing macros from the LaTeX kernel to produce the macros ultimately expected by the LaTeX font selection system.
- **v3** is completely different. It produces *expandably* the UTF-8 bytes. It does not use inputenc at all but does produce active leading bytes so that it is "inputenc+utf8" ready. The active tokens are protected using `\protect` (no e-TeX `\protected` here), and to write them to file stream one needs to issue `\set@display@protect`. They can be use inside an `\edef`, but need the LaTeX `\protected@edef` for that, for the same reason. Also macro `\UniToUTF` now admits numerical input, so that the `"` must be explicitely used in case of hexadecimal input (I do not understand why LaTeX's `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` contrarily to `utf8x`'s one does not do that either). The advantage here is that it is easy to set-up loops producing such characters in a row using an associated counter or other devices. For the sake of illustrating this, the mwe uses package `xinttools` but this is only for the examples.

---

#### v1

Here is quickly jotted down hack which seems to achieve with pdflatex what you want. May need some corrections for working in general, (short on time today).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{Hallo}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\unicodetoutf[1]{{\count@ "#1 \parse@XML@charref}%
   \UTFviii@tmp}
\let\@preamblecmds\@empty
\makeatother


\begin{document}

€ ^^e2^^82^^ac \unicodetoutf{20AC} %<-- should output Hallo

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### v2

Here is edit to address issues about avoiding `\let\@preamblecmds\@empty` and allowing ascii chars:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

%\tracingmacros1
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{Hallo}
%\tracingmacros0

\makeatletter
\let\UF@parse@UTFviii@a\parse@UTFviii@a
\let\UF@parse@UTFviii@b\parse@UTFviii@b
\newcommand*\UF@parse@XML@charref{%
  \ifnum\count@<"A0\relax
     \xdef\UTFviii@tmp{\char\the\count@\space}% \count@ not globally modified
  \else\ifnum\count@<"800\relax
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@a,%
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@b C\UTFviii@two@octets.,%
  \else\ifnum\count@<"10000\relax
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@a;%
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@a,%
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@b E\UTFviii@three@octets.{,;}%
   \else
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@a;%
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@a,%
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@a!%
     \UF@parse@UTFviii@b F\UTFviii@four@octets.{!,;}%
    \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand\unicodetoutf[1]{%
  {\count@ "#1 \UF@parse@XML@charref}%
   \UTFviii@tmp
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

€ ^^e2^^82^^ac \unicodetoutf{20AC} %<-- should output Hallo

A ^^41 \unicodetoutf{0041}

e ^^65 \unicodetoutf{0065}

é ^^c3^^a9 \unicodetoutf{00E9}

\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont

α ^^ce^^b1 \unicodetoutf{03B1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to plug into the `utf8.def` Unicode to UTF-8 already coded parsing by the LaTeX team.

---

#### v3

Here is the expandable method. I long hesitated with the 7bit ascii range and the problems with catcodes, to start with many of them are declared ignored tokens by TeX/LaTeX. In the end I decided that all will be produced with catcode 12. However, when writing out to a file, they will nevertheless be sometimes output in TeX's core `^^` notation, not as genuine UTF-8 7bit ascii bytes.

It is not completely obvious to set-up macros expanding to all those tokens as catcode 12 tokens, I have chosen a rather systematic way rather than use shortcuts.

Please check out the code comments for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

% First, the most complicated, define macros extending to catcode 12
% tokens in the 7bit ascii range. Unfortunately, when writing out
% to a file, some of them will get converted back to ^^ notation, and
% not be written there as UTF-8 bytes.

%% 7bit ASCII RANGE (with all its TeX catcode complications)

%% First we handle the upper part (ascii code 127 handled later)

\begingroup
\catcode`\^ 12
\catcode`\_ 12
\catcode`\{ 12
\catcode`\} 12
\catcode`\~ 12
\catcode`\? 0
\catcode`\< 1
\catcode`\> 2
\catcode`\\ 12
?def?y<?endgroup
?count@ 64
?@tfor?x:=%
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO%
PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_%
`abcdefghijklmno%
pqrstuvwxyz{|}~?do<%
    ?expandafter?xdef?csname utf8byte?the?count@?endcsname<?expandafter?string?x>%
    ?advance?count@?@ne>%
>?y

%% Now we handle the lower part

\begingroup
\catcode127 14
\def\z{utf8byte}%
\def\x{%
\count@ 0
\loop
  \catcode\count@ 12
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\count@<64
\repeat}\x^^?
\def\y{^^?
\count@=0\relax^^?
\@tfor\x:=^^?
^^@^^A^^B^^C^^D^^E^^F^^G^^H^^I^^J^^K^^L^^M^^N^^O^^?
^^P^^Q^^R^^S^^T^^U^^V^^W^^X^^Y^^Z^^[^^\^^]^^^^^_^^?
^^`^^a^^b^^c^^d^^e^^f^^g^^h^^i^^j^^k^^l^^m^^n^^o^^?
^^p^^q^^r^^s^^t^^u^^v^^w^^x^^y^^z^^{^^|^^}^^~\do{^^?
\expandafter\xdef\csname\z\the\count@\endcsname{\x}^^?
\advance\count@\@ne}}^^?
\y\endgroup

%% ascii codes 63 and 127 were not handled yet

\@namedef{utf8byte63}{?}%

\begingroup
\catcode127 12
\global\@namedef{utf8byte127}{^^?}%
\endgroup

%% Now, the easier part, we define the UTF-8 continuation bytes
%% (catcode 12) and the UTF-8 leading bytes (as \protect'ed active
%% tokens). This set-up is ready for utf8+inputenc but does not need
%% it for its definitions. (this document does not load inputenc)
%% UPDATE: but LaTeX newer than 2018/04/01 loads inputenc+utf8 per
%% default, so a small change has been made below.

%% CONTINUATION BYTES

\begingroup
% prior to LaTeX 2018/04/01 these 64 bytes were assigned catcode12
% by LaTeX in absence of inputenc; but nowadays these bytes are active
% by default. Hence I modified \x into \expandafter\string\x which
% works whether or not the document incorporating this code is with 
% old (with or without utf8+inputenc) LaTeX or with newer LaTeX
\count@ "80
\@tfor\x:=%
^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
\do{\expandafter\xdef\csname utf8byte\the\count@\endcsname{\expandafter\string\x}%
    \advance\count@\@ne}%

%% LEADING BYTES

%% we will make them TeX active, as inputenc does with utf8
%% We \protect them à la LaTeX, and writing to a file will
%% have to be made in a \set@display@protect context

\count@ "C2
\loop
\catcode\count@\active
\advance\count@ 1
\ifnum\count@ < "F5
\repeat

\count@ "C2

\@tfor\x:=^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4%
\do{\expandafter\protected@xdef
      \csname utf8byte\the\count@\endcsname{\expandafter\protect\x}%
    \advance\count@\@ne}%

\endgroup

%% Time now to define our expandable Unicode to UTF-8 converter

%% a "case-switch" utility
\long\def\xintdothis #1#2\xintorthat #3{\fi #1}%
\let\xintorthat \@firstofone

%% EXPANDABLE UNICODE TO UTF-8 BYTES CONVERTER

%% The macro accepts any numexpr compatible input.
%% This means hexadecimal input must be prefixed by "
%% (and must use uppercase hex digits.)
%% Advantage with such numerical inputs is to allow easy usage
%% over some arithmetic range with counts or counters.

%% NOTE: \numexpr is the only e-TeX extension used.

\newcommand*\UniToUTF[1]{\expandafter\UniToUTF@\the\numexpr#1.}%

\def\UniToUTF@ #1.{%
  \ifnum#1<"80 \xintdothis\uni@ascii\fi
  \ifnum#1<"800 \xintdothis\uni@twooctets\fi
  \ifnum#1<"10000 \xintdothis\uni@threeoctets\fi
%% maybe add here some out of range check ?
  \xintorthat\uni@fouroctets {#1}%
}

%% CONVERSION FORMULAS MORALLY BASED ON EXPLANATIONS OF
%% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
%% USING OCTAL NOTATION

\def\uni@ascii#1{\csname utf8byte#1\endcsname}%

\def\uni@twooctets#1{\expandafter\uni@twooctets@i
    \the\numexpr(#1+32)/64-1.#1.}%
\def\uni@twooctets@i#1.#2.{%
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr192+#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \endcsname
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr128+#2-#1*64\endcsname
}%

\def\uni@threeoctets#1{\expandafter\uni@threeoctets@i
    \the\numexpr(#1+32)/64-1.#1.}%
\def\uni@threeoctets@i#1.#2.{\expandafter\uni@threeoctets@ii
    \the\numexpr(#1+32)/64-1\expandafter.%
    \the\numexpr#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter.%
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr128+#2-#1*64\endcsname}%
\def\uni@threeoctets@ii#1.#2.{%
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr224+#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \endcsname
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr128+#2-#1*64\endcsname
}%

\def\uni@fouroctets#1{\expandafter\uni@fouroctets@i
    \the\numexpr(#1+32)/64-1.#1.}%
\def\uni@fouroctets@i#1.#2.{\expandafter\uni@fouroctets@ii
    \the\numexpr(#1+32)/64-1\expandafter.%
    \the\numexpr#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter.%
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr128+#2-#1*64\endcsname}%
\def\uni@fouroctets@ii#1.#2.{\expandafter\uni@fouroctets@iii
    \the\numexpr(#1+32)/64-1\expandafter.%
    \the\numexpr#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter.%
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr128+#2-#1*64\endcsname}%
\def\uni@fouroctets@iii#1.#2.{%
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr240+#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \endcsname
    \csname utf8byte\the\numexpr128+#2-#1*64\endcsname}%

\makeatother

% xinttools loaded only for easying up loops in illustrative code

\usepackage{xinttools}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars}[2]{%
% #1 = starting Unicode code point
% #2 = out stream
  \begingroup
    \set@display@protect %%<<<---- makes \protect=\string
    \def\mymacro##1{\UniToUTF{#1+##1}}%
    \immediate\write#2{\xintApplyUnbraced\mymacro{\xintSeq{0}{63}}}%
  \endgroup
}

% For \edef we need to take into account  LaTeX's protection mechanism
% for the UTF-8
% leading bytes, as we defined them to be active for inputenc+utf8 readiness.
\begingroup
\global\let\protectedATedef\protected@edef
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\protectedATedef\x{\UniToUTF{"20AC}}
\typeout{\meaning\x}
\typeout{\x}
\typeout{\UniToUTF{"20AC}}
\typeout{}
\protectedATedef\x{\UniToUTF{"03B1}}
\typeout{\meaning\x}
\typeout{\x}
\typeout{\UniToUTF{"03B1}}
\typeout{}
\protectedATedef\x{\UniToUTF{"0416}}
\typeout{\meaning\x}
\typeout{\x}
\typeout{\UniToUTF{"0416}}

{\catcode127 12
\if\UniToUTF{127}\string^^?\else\ERROR\fi
}
\if\UniToUTF{126}\string~\else\ERROR\fi

{\makeatletter
\if\UniToUTF{37}\expandafter\@gobble\string\%\else\ERROR\fi}

\newwrite\foo

\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname ASCIIMEANINGS.txt

% we don't use \typeout here, but write to another file,
% else Emacs/AUCTeX wrongly
% reports a compilation error due to misinterpreation of log
% containing the ! character

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\set@display@protect %%<<<---- makes \protect=\string
\xintFor* #1 in{\xintSeq{0}{127}}\do
{\protectedATedef\x{\UniToUTF{#1}}%
 \immediate\write\foo{\UniToUTF{#1} (\meaning\x)}}
\endgroup

\immediate\closeout\foo

\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname ASCII.txt

\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"0000}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"0040}\foo

\immediate\closeout\foo

\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname0380.txt

\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"0380}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"03C0}\foo

\immediate\closeout\foo

\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname0400.txt

\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"0400}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"0440}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"0480}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"04C0}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"0500}\foo

\immediate\closeout\foo

\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname2000.txt

\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"2000}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"2040}\foo

\immediate\closeout\foo

\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname4000.txt

\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"4000}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"4040}\foo

\immediate\closeout\foo

\immediate\openout\foo=\jobname10000.txt

\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"10000}\foo
\WriteOutSixtyFourUTFchars{"10040}\foo

\immediate\closeout\foo
\end{document}
```

To illustrate the functioning here is what one finds in log:

```
macro:->\protect €
€
€

macro:->\protect α
α
α

macro:->\protect Ж
Ж
Ж
```

then in file `\jobname ASCII.txt`

```
^^@^^A^^B^^C^^D^^E^^F^^G^^H 
^^L^^M^^N^^O^^P^^Q^^R^^S^^T^^U^^V^^W^^X^^Y^^Z^^[^^\^^]^^^^^_ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~^^?
```

(the `CTRL-I`, `CTRL-J`, `CTRL-K` are genuine bytes)

then in file `\jobname ASCIIMEANINGS.txt` (this is from default situation, one wonders why `CTRL-K` which is vertical tabulation is handled as genuine byte... see remark below about pdflatex's `-8bit` option ...)

```
^^@ (macro:->^^@)
^^A (macro:->^^A)
^^B (macro:->^^B)
^^C (macro:->^^C)
^^D (macro:->^^D)
^^E (macro:->^^E)
^^F (macro:->^^F)
^^G (macro:->^^G)
^^H (macro:->^^H)
     (macro:->  )

 (macro:->
)
 (macro:->)
^^L (macro:->^^L)
^^M (macro:->^^M)
^^N (macro:->^^N)
^^O (macro:->^^O)
^^P (macro:->^^P)
^^Q (macro:->^^Q)
^^R (macro:->^^R)
^^S (macro:->^^S)
^^T (macro:->^^T)
^^U (macro:->^^U)
^^V (macro:->^^V)
^^W (macro:->^^W)
^^X (macro:->^^X)
^^Y (macro:->^^Y)
^^Z (macro:->^^Z)
^^[ (macro:->^^[)
^^\ (macro:->^^\)
^^] (macro:->^^])
^^^ (macro:->^^^)
^^_ (macro:->^^_)
  (macro:-> )
! (macro:->!)
" (macro:->")
# (macro:->#)
$ (macro:->$)
% (macro:->%)
& (macro:->&)
' (macro:->')
( (macro:->()
) (macro:->))
* (macro:->*)
+ (macro:->+)
, (macro:->,)
- (macro:->-)
. (macro:->.)
/ (macro:->/)
0 (macro:->0)
1 (macro:->1)
2 (macro:->2)
3 (macro:->3)
4 (macro:->4)
5 (macro:->5)
6 (macro:->6)
7 (macro:->7)
8 (macro:->8)
9 (macro:->9)
: (macro:->:)
; (macro:->;)
< (macro:-><)
= (macro:->=)
> (macro:->>)
? (macro:->?)
@ (macro:->@)
A (macro:->A)
B (macro:->B)
C (macro:->C)
D (macro:->D)
E (macro:->E)
F (macro:->F)
G (macro:->G)
H (macro:->H)
I (macro:->I)
J (macro:->J)
K (macro:->K)
L (macro:->L)
M (macro:->M)
N (macro:->N)
O (macro:->O)
P (macro:->P)
Q (macro:->Q)
R (macro:->R)
S (macro:->S)
T (macro:->T)
U (macro:->U)
V (macro:->V)
W (macro:->W)
X (macro:->X)
Y (macro:->Y)
Z (macro:->Z)
[ (macro:->[)
\ (macro:->\)
] (macro:->])
^ (macro:->^)
_ (macro:->_)
` (macro:->`)
a (macro:->a)
b (macro:->b)
c (macro:->c)
d (macro:->d)
e (macro:->e)
f (macro:->f)
g (macro:->g)
h (macro:->h)
i (macro:->i)
j (macro:->j)
k (macro:->k)
l (macro:->l)
m (macro:->m)
n (macro:->n)
o (macro:->o)
p (macro:->p)
q (macro:->q)
r (macro:->r)
s (macro:->s)
t (macro:->t)
u (macro:->u)
v (macro:->v)
w (macro:->w)
x (macro:->x)
y (macro:->y)
z (macro:->z)
{ (macro:->{)
| (macro:->|)
} (macro:->})
~ (macro:->~)
^^? (macro:->^^?)
```

**Important update**: to get genuine bytes for the entire 7bit ascii range, use `pdflatex -8bit` !

then in file `\jobname 0380.txt`

```
΁΂΃΄΅Ά·ΈΉΊ΋Ό΍ΎΏΐΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡ΢ΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβγδεζηθικλμνξο
πρςστυφχψωϊϋόύώϏϐϑϒϓϔϕϖϗϘϙϚϛϜϝϞϟϠϡϢϣϤϥϦϧϨϩϪϫϬϭϮϯϰϱϲϳϴϵ϶ϷϸϹϺϻϼϽϾϿ
```

then in file `\jobname 0400.txt`

```
ЀЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЍЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмноп
рстуфхцчшщъыьэюяѐёђѓєѕіїјљњћќѝўџѠѡѢѣѤѥѦѧѨѩѪѫѬѭѮѯѰѱѲѳѴѵѶѷѸѹѺѻѼѽѾѿ
Ҁҁ҂҃҄҅҆҇҈҉ҊҋҌҍҎҏҐґҒғҔҕҖҗҘҙҚқҜҝҞҟҠҡҢңҤҥҦҧҨҩҪҫҬҭҮүҰұҲҳҴҵҶҷҸҹҺһҼҽҾҿ
ӀӁӂӃӄӅӆӇӈӉӊӋӌӍӎӏӐӑӒӓӔӕӖӗӘәӚӛӜӝӞӟӠӡӢӣӤӥӦӧӨөӪӫӬӭӮӯӰӱӲӳӴӵӶӷӸӹӺӻӼӽӾӿ
ԀԁԂԃԄԅԆԇԈԉԊԋԌԍԎԏԐԑԒԓԔԕԖԗԘԙԚԛԜԝԞԟԠԡԢԣԤԥԦԧԨԩԪԫԬԭԮԯ԰ԱԲԳԴԵԶԷԸԹԺԻԼԽԾԿ
```

then in file `\jobname 4000.txt`

```
䀀䀁䀂䀃䀄䀅䀆䀇䀈䀉䀊䀋䀌䀍䀎䀏䀐䀑䀒䀓䀔䀕䀖䀗䀘䀙䀚䀛䀜䀝䀞䀟䀠䀡䀢䀣䀤䀥䀦䀧䀨䀩䀪䀫䀬䀭䀮䀯䀰䀱䀲䀳䀴䀵䀶䀷䀸䀹䀺䀻䀼䀽䀾䀿
䁀䁁䁂䁃䁄䁅䁆䁇䁈䁉䁊䁋䁌䁍䁎䁏䁐䁑䁒䁓䁔䁕䁖䁗䁘䁙䁚䁛䁜䁝䁞䁟䁠䁡䁢䁣䁤䁥䁦䁧䁨䁩䁪䁫䁬䁭䁮䁯䁰䁱䁲䁳䁴䁵䁶䁷䁸䁹䁺䁻䁼䁽䁾䁿
```

as examples. Rendering in your browser will depend on its font set-up.

Here is the `\jobname 10000.txt` file as it shows in an Emacs buffer:

[image]

Update of an image to show how the ASCIIMEANINGS file renders in an Emacs buffer, proving the `^^K` is indeed a one-byte there, in the default usage of `pdflatex`:

[image]

**Important added note**

This is the default situation, but using `pdflatex -8bit` solves all our
anguishes, here is Emacs buffer screen shot of ASCII output file:

[image]

Thus the `-8bit` option we can indeed create arbitrary UTF-8 encoded files from within pdflatex, using only Unicode code points as input.

Comment: This looks like a very good start. `\let\@preamblecmds\@empty` is a bit drastic, so one should probably better create copies of the relevant definitions from inputenc and a bit code for the ascii range is needed (`\unicodetoutf{0065}` breaks currently), but this are details ;-)).

Comment: Looks cool, I look forward to reading this answer and understanding what it does… I'm just curious why you say “(pdflatex only answer)” at the top, as the question is specifically about pdflatex (that is, about doing in pdflatex what is trivial in lualatex).

Comment: I think this question and answers serve as a good advertisement for LuaTeX :-)

Comment: Remarks: ``1.)`` the `\UniToUTF` macro could be modified to need exactly two expansions steps leading to say  ``\protect^^e2^^82^^ac``, ``2.)`` it is possible to be more economical in macros, currently the code needs the preliminary construction of `128 + 64 + 51 = 243` macros i.e. one for each valid UTF-8 byte, but this could be replaced by some giant `\ifcase` macros. I think however the present way is better, also for trace purposes.

Comment: Both answers are very good and useful. But the system here doesn't allow me to give both the same bonus, so I'm accepting this one and giving the other the second bonus. Not perfect but I don't know a fairer solution;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer good that you awarded another bonus because it gave me opportunity to fix the catcodes of the continuation bytes. My macros assumed inputenc was not yet loaded, so I had spared a `\string`. LaTeX 2018/04/01 has modified the context so I added it to sanitize those catcodes (needed for `\edef` things and writing to files). Perhaps also I should have provided an `\edefUTFtext\foo{list of Unicode code points}` doing the `\protected@edef` mentioned in my code comments and examples.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{Hallo}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{12345}{Bye}
\begin{document}
```

There are two parts to doing what the question desires:

- Converting a Unicode code point to its UTF-8 encoding, e.g. U+20AC to the sequence of bytes `E2 82 AC`.
- Injecting those bytes, or the equivalent of typing those bytes, into the input stream.

---

The first part is a UTF-8 encoder. It's already implemented in `utf8ienc.dtx` / `utf8.def`, but a fresh implementation is below. It was fun to write, and is different from the official implementation. (For one thing, it uses the e-TeX extension `\numexpr` which could not be assumed when that original implementation was written… but apart from using that new primitive, it does not use any external macros, and works in both plain (e)TeX and LaTeX.)

This is how it works (and how [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=UTF-8&oldid=808178865#Description) is defined): Given a number `n` (which stands for a Unicode codepoint, e.g. `"20AC` is the number 8364, representing the codepoint [U+20AC Euro Sign](https://codepoints.net/U+20AC)),

- Look at the size of `n`, to determine how many bytes will be the UTF-8 encoding
- Peel off six bits at a time from the right: these bits, with `10` prefixed, become the rightmost bytes
- For the first byte, use the leftover bits with a prefix that depends on the number of bytes

The code which does it:

```
% Division and remainder. Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34449/48 but with bugs fixed. Note: assumes #2 positive
\def\modulo#1#2{\ifnum \numexpr(#1 - (#1/#2)*(#2))\relax < 0 (#1 - (#1/#2)*(#2) + #2) \else (#1 - (#1/#2)*(#2)) \fi}
\def\truncdiv#1#2{((#1 - \modulo{#1}{#2})/(#2))}
% The hypothetical continuation bytes: last byte, the one before that, etc.
\def\utfByteLastOne  #1{\numexpr(128 + \modulo{#1}{64})\relax}
\def\utfByteLastTwo  #1{\numexpr(128 + \modulo{\truncdiv{#1}{64}}{64})\relax}
\def\utfByteLastThree#1{\numexpr(128 + \modulo{\truncdiv{#1}{(64*64)}}{64})\relax}
\def\utfByteLastFour #1{\numexpr(128 + \modulo{\truncdiv{#1}{(64*64*64)}}{64})\relax}
% The actual individual bytes in the stream, for lengths 1 to 4.
\def\utfStreamOneByteOne    #1{#1}
\def\utfStreamTwoByteOne    #1{\numexpr(\utfByteLastTwo{#1} + 64)\relax}
\def\utfStreamTwoByteTwo    #1{\utfByteLastOne{#1}}
\def\utfStreamThreeByteOne  #1{\numexpr(\utfByteLastThree{#1} + 96)\relax}
\def\utfStreamThreeByteTwo  #1{\utfByteLastTwo{#1}}
\def\utfStreamThreeByteThree#1{\utfByteLastOne{#1}}
\def\utfStreamFourByteOne   #1{\numexpr(\utfByteLastFour{#1} + 112)\relax}
\def\utfStreamFourByteTwo   #1{\utfByteLastThree{#1}}
\def\utfStreamFourByteThree #1{\utfByteLastTwo{#1}}
\def\utfStreamFourByteFour  #1{\utfByteLastOne{#1}}
% Expands to \utfCallbackOne{#1} or ... or \utfCallbackFour{#1} depending on whether the code point #1 has 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes in its UTF-8 encoding.
\def\utfStreamFromNumber#1{%
    \ifnum #1 < 128
        \utfCallbackOne{#1}%
    \else \ifnum #1 < 2048  % 2^11
              \utfCallbackTwo{#1}%
          \else \ifnum #1 < 65536  % 2^16
                    \utfCallbackThree{#1}%
                \else
                    \utfCallbackFour{#1}%
                \fi
          \fi
    \fi
}
```

The interface of this UTF-8 encoder is quite general (and also completely independent of `inputenc`) in the sense that you can simply redefine the `\utfCallbackOne` to `\utfCallbackFour` macros, to do different things with the bytes of the UTF-8 stream. For example, see the [first revision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/399380/1) of this answer for a version that simply prints out the bytes (and without `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`).

---

The second part (injecting arbitrary bytes/tokens into the input stream, as if the user had typed them) is straightforward in LuaTeX, but nontrivial in other engines. Firstly, if all we want to do is emulate what *`inputenc`* would have done if those tokens were inserted (which is what the question asks for), then we can use the fact that `inputenc` stores the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` definitions in internal macros named `u8:<byte1><byte2><byte3>` etc., and simply invoke those macros. The code below uses the `\lccode` and `\lowercase` trick (inspired by `utf8ienc.dtx`) to construct the macro names that have “special” bytes in them.

```
% These get the full byte stream -- here, do whatever you want with the individual bytes.
% In this case, these callbacks call internal control sequences u8:... defined by \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
\def\utfCallbackOne  #1{{\char\utfStreamOneByteOne{#1}}}
\def\utfCallbackTwo  #1{{\lccode`A=\utfStreamTwoByteOne{#1}\lccode`B=\utfStreamTwoByteTwo{#1}\lowercase{\csname u8:AB\endcsname}}}
\def\utfCallbackThree#1{{\lccode`A=\utfStreamThreeByteOne{#1}\lccode`B=\utfStreamThreeByteTwo{#1}\lccode`C=\utfStreamThreeByteThree{#1}\lowercase{\csname u8:ABC\endcsname}}}
\def\utfCallbackFour #1{{\lccode`A=\utfStreamFourByteOne{#1}\lccode`B=\utfStreamFourByteTwo{#1}\lccode`C=\utfStreamFourByteThree{#1}\lccode`D=\utfStreamFourByteFour{#1}\lowercase{\csname u8:ABCD\endcsname}}}
\newcommand\unicodetoutf[1]{\utfStreamFromNumber{"#1}}

€ ^^e2^^82^^ac \unicodetoutf{20AC}

© ^^c2^^a9 \unicodetoutf{00A9}

 ^^f0^^92^^8d^^85 \unicodetoutf{12345}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

But this is “cheating” in some sense: we're using the fact that we know the internal names of the macros, to call them. Also, if we use a character that has not been given a definition with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, then `\csname u8:...` has no definition and TeX treats it as `\relax`, so we get no error — so we need a wrapper that first checks whether it has been defined, for which we need to reproduce or borrow more from `inputenc`.

Instead, we can extend the `\lccode`/`\lowercase` trick to get the effect of having typed those characters, *without* assuming anything about the internals of `inputenc`. Let's think about it: why can't we just write `\lowercase{AB}`, after setting the `\lccode`s of `A` and `B`? It's because `\lowercase` changes the character codes, but not the category codes. So we need to change the category codes of `A` and `B` as well, to be the same as those of the bytes in the UTF-8 stream. But even after doing that, if we say `\lowercase{AB}` inside the macro, then it picks up the catcodes at the time of reading the macro, which is not what we want. One solution I was able to find was `\scantokens` (introduced in e-TeX). Using it, we can get a “true” solution, with no “cheating”: replace the previous snippet with:

```
% The full byte stream -- here, do whatever you want with the individual bytes.
\newcount\charX
\newcount\charY
\newcount\charZ
\newcount\charW
\def\utfCallbackOne  #1{{%
    \charX=\utfStreamOneByteOne{#1}%
    \catcode255=\catcode\charX%
    \lccode255=\charX%
    \lowercase{\scantokens{^^ff\endlinechar=-1}}}}
\def\utfCallbackTwo  #1{{%
   \charX=\utfStreamTwoByteOne{#1}%
   \charY=\utfStreamTwoByteTwo{#1}%
   \catcode`X=\catcode\charX%
   \catcode`Y=\catcode\charY%
   \lccode`X=\charX%
   \lccode`Y=\charY%
   \lowercase{\scantokens{XY\endlinechar=-1}}}}
\def\utfCallbackThree#1{{%
   \charX=\utfStreamThreeByteOne{#1}%
   \charY=\utfStreamThreeByteTwo{#1}%
   \charZ=\utfStreamThreeByteThree{#1}%
   \catcode`X=\catcode\charX%
   \catcode`Y=\catcode\charY%
   \catcode`Z=\catcode\charZ%
   \lccode`X=\charX%
   \lccode`Y=\charY%
   \lccode`Z=\charZ%
   \lowercase{\scantokens{XYZ\endlinechar=-1}}}}
\def\utfCallbackFour #1{{%
   \charX=\utfStreamFourByteOne{#1}%
   \charY=\utfStreamFourByteTwo{#1}%
   \charZ=\utfStreamFourByteThree{#1}%
   \charW=\utfStreamFourByteFour{#1}%
   \catcode`X=\catcode\charX%
   \catcode`Y=\catcode\charY%
   \catcode`Z=\catcode\charZ%
   \catcode`W=\catcode\charW%
   \lccode`X=\charX%
   \lccode`Y=\charY%
   \lccode`Z=\charZ%
   \lccode`W=\charW%
   \lowercase{\scantokens{XYZW\endlinechar=-1}}}}
\newcommand\unicodetoutf[1]{\utfStreamFromNumber{"#1}}

A ^^41 \unicodetoutf{0041}

\def~{what}
~ ^^7e \unicodetoutf{007E}

€ ^^e2^^82^^ac \unicodetoutf{20AC}

© ^^c2^^a9 \unicodetoutf{00A9}

 ^^f0^^92^^8d^^85 \unicodetoutf{12345}

\end{document}
```

Now everything works! The same output as before, and in each case we have injected tokens equivalent to having typed out those Unicode characters in the file directly.

Comment: Wow. Two remarks: I tried with non declared chars (e.g. 300C). The first version silently drops it (not so good), while the second gives the standard inputenc error (better). I also tried what happens in a \edef context (the luatex version is expandable): the first doesn't give an error but neither the correct output, the second a `! File ended while scanning definition of \test.`. Here too I think the second reaction is better - a clear error is better than wrong output.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point about the non-declared characters. I added a mention in the answer. I also fixed the answer to deal properly with ASCII characters, so that for example, both `\unicodetoutf{0041}` and `\unicodetoutf{007E}` do the right thing (be equivalent to typing `A` and `~` respectively), despite the different catcodes. (May still not be perfect… looking.) About using it in an expandable context… interesting to explore, though I feel I may have reached the limits of my ability or motivation :D

Comment: Both answers are very good and useful. But the system here doesn't allow me to give both the same bonus, so I'm accepting the other and give this the second bonus. Not perfect but I don't know a fairer solution;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, that's kind of you! (The answer by jfbu is of course more extensive/expert and better for macro-programming as it will work “expandably”.)

Answer (score 3):

This directly implements the Unicode to UTF-8 conversion algorithm, in fully expandable way.

It uses the standard feature that an UTF-8 sequence `abcd` (at most four characters) is transformed into the control sequence `\u8:abcd`.

If the Unicode point is not defined, `pdflatex` stops with an error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ERROR 
                  BAD UTF (U+AAAA)
l.98 \unicodetoutf{AAAA}
```

Here's the code

```
% algorithm from https://home.kpn.nl/vanadovv/uni/utf8conversion.html

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\unicodetoutf}{m}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { "#1 < 128 }
   {
    \char_generate:nn { "#1 } { 12 }
   }
   {
    \egreg_unicodetoutf:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \egreg_unicodetoutf:n
 {
  \__egreg_unicodetoutf:nf { #1 }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { "#1 < 2048 }
     {
      \__egreg_unicodetoutf_two:n { #1 }
     }
     {
      \int_compare:nTF { "#1 < 65536 }
       {
        \__egreg_unicodetoutf_three:n { #1 }
       }
       {
        \__egreg_unicodetoutf_four:n { #1 }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_unicodetoutf:nn
 {
  \cs_if_exist_use:cF { #2 } { \ERROR BAD~UTF~(U+#1) }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__egreg_unicodetoutf:nn { nf }

\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_unicodetoutf_two:n
 {
  u8:
  \char_generate:nn { 192 + \int_div_truncate:nn { "#1 } { 64 } } { 12 }
  \char_generate:nn { 128 + \int_mod:nn { "#1 } { 64 } } { 12 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_unicodetoutf_three:n
 {
  u8:
  \char_generate:nn { 224 + \int_div_truncate:nn { "#1 } { 4096} } { 12 }
  \char_generate:nn
   {
    128 + \int_mod:nn { \int_div_truncate:nn { "#1 } { 64 } } { 64 }
   }
   { 12 }
  \char_generate:nn { 128 + \int_mod:nn { "#1 } { 64 } } { 12 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__egreg_unicodetoutf_four:n
 {
  u8:
  \char_generate:nn { 240 + \int_div_truncate:nn { "#1 } { 262144 } } { 12 }
  \char_generate:nn
   {
    128 + \int_mod:nn { \int_div_truncate:nn { "#1 } { 4096 } } { 64 }
   }
   { 12 }
  \char_generate:nn
   {
    128 + \int_mod:nn { \int_div_truncate:nn { "#1 } { 64 } } { 64 }
   }
   { 12 }
  \char_generate:nn { 128 + \int_mod:nn { "#1 } { 64 } } { 12 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E9}{b}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{Hallo}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{10006}{World}

\begin{document}

a ^^61 \unicodetoutf{0061}

é ^^c3^^a9 \unicodetoutf{00E9}

€ ^^e2^^82^^ac \unicodetoutf{20AC} %<-- should output Hallo

 ^^f0^^90^^80^^86 \unicodetoutf{10006} % should output World

\edef\temp{\unicodetoutf{20AC}}
\texttt{\meaning\temp}

\unicodetoutf{AAAA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling we have something similar for internal set up in the case changer ...

Comment: @JosephWright It might be possible to generate the UTF-8 character sequence, but, alas, `\char_generate:nn { <number> } { 13 }` doesn't stop at the generated character if used in `e` expansion. Perhaps adding `\exp_not:N` in front might be an idea.

Comment: I haven't thought about this question in 11 months (since I wrote an answer), but does this not have the problem regarding characters with no definition (see the paragraph in my answer containing “cheating”)?

Comment: If one use `\tl_use:c` instead of `\use:c` one get an error if one tries to call an undeclared value, e.g. `\unicodetoutf{0409}`. That's imho better and more in line to the direct input `Љ`. Could this have drawbacks?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'd say that this is exploiting a hidden feature. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg but a useful one ;-).  Would it make sense to have a variant of `\use:c` which errors in a similar way?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There is `\cs_if_exist_use:cF`. I'll review this later.

Comment: @egreg yes, I know, but there one has to add the error message explicitly. I was pondering about a standard command that always gives the standard "undefined command" error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is the new version better?

Comment: Yes, that was what I had more or less in mind on the team list ;-). And now I have to figure out a way to get the bonus even again - why did I start with this?