# How do I insert a japanese character with unicode?

Tags: texlive, unicode, japanese

I want to insert a handful of Japanese (katakana) characters in a latex document. I am using texlive and pdflatex.

I know I can use a Japanese typesetting package, such as `CJK`, and do something like this:

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
ァィ
\end{CJK}
```

but I don't want to actually type (or copy/paste) the characters themselves, and I'd rather use the corresponding unicode, e.g. `U+30A1`.

I have tried `\symbol{30A1}` and `\unichar{''30A1}` with the packages:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

but neither work. I believe the corresponding fonts are installed, so maybe I am doing something wrong with the unicode?

Comment: Not an easy problem see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399260/input-tokens-through-the-unicode-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bxcjkjatype}
\begin{document}
\begin{uCJK}\UTF{30A1}\end{uCJK}
\end{document}
```